# É possível criar uma aplicação em C/C++ para Android?

Tags: android, c, c++, mobile, interoperabilidade

Quero criar uma aplicação para Android usando a linguagem C ou C++. Quais são as vantagens e desvantagens disto?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 17):

Sim, é possível, Existe algo chamado [NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html) (fantástico o tradutor usado nesse site, traduziu até o código :) ).

- Obviamente você terá mais performance
- eventualmente seja melhor ou mais fácil fazer algumas coisas específicas
- tem muito mais controle sobre a memória, pode evitar o *garbage collector*
- pode usar bibliotecas desejadas nessas linguagens de forma direta
- talvez esteja usando uma linguagem que esteja mais confortável.

Se lembrar de algo mais eu posto depois.

- É mais difícil programar nessas linguagens, é fácil cometer mais erros e criar insegurança, é menos produtivo
- não é a linguagem principal, precisa interoperar com a JVM do Android
- algumas coisas do Android são mais difíceis de usar com o NDK.

Aqui vai um chute, vai de Java ou C#, mesmo você dizendo pouco eu consigo inferir que é o caminho mais adequado para seu caso :)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Neste momento preciso programar em c++, java ainda nao domino bem ...preciso criar uma APP a cada liguagem que eu estudo ...

Answer (score 4):

Bom, para aplicações normais não vejo vantagens, tanto que conheci ndk pensei que era possível criar aplicações 100% em C/C++, mas não é bem assim, tanto que algo que mais me iludiu foi o fato de existir views nativas no estilo findViewById pegando pelo xml, recomendo usar para aplicações que precise de desempenho como um emulador ou um jogo, neste caso você vai poder criar em 98% C/C++ puro.

Answer (score 0):

Sim é possível, Para Android/Ios usando o C++ Builder da Embarcadero IDE RAD

https://www.embarcadero.com/br/products/cbuilder/features/mobile

Se precisar que aplicativos funcionem rapidamente em aparelhos móveis, o ARC é a melhor opção de gestão de memória disponível. Compile códigos Delphi e C++ para aparelhos móveis com implementações ARC completas, possibilitando que seus aplicativos operem de forma rápida e sem problemas independentemente do hardware.

Coletores de lixo, como aqueles usados por aplicativos desenvolvidos em .net e Java, exigem 4 vezes a memória disponível do ARC para alcançar o desempenho. Ser inteligente com a memória limitada em aparelhos móveis significa que o ARC evita grandes coletores de lixo que reduzem o desempenho nas plataformas móveis.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]