# Tem alguma forma de Implementar um Executável de C para Mobile?

Tags: c, mobile, app

Bora lá;
Consegui desenvolver um executável bem banaca em C que escreve em Arquivo para que eu armazene alguns dados. Mas, eu queria que esse executável que já está prontinho rodando no Desktop também rodasse em Celulares, tem alguma forma direta de eu Pegar  o Executável e Criar um aplicativo Mobile com ele?

Comment: Difícil de entender. Você já tem um programa escrito em C? C não é uma linguagem de script.

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a ajuda for muito simples ainda é possível fazer nos comentários.

Comment: simplificando, preciso pegar um executável de C e transformar ele em um Aplicativo.

Answer (score 0):

Em resumo, você quer converter C para Android, é isso?

Temos alguns casos de sucesso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/209455/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-criar-uma-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-c-c-para-android), [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002164/write-applications-in-c-or-c-for-android), [aqui](https://www.clubedohardware.com.br/forums/topic/872728-rodar-programa-em-c-no-android/) e [aqui](https://insights.dice.com/2016/02/03/5-reasons-to-use-c-for-android-development/).

Se resumirmos a resposta, podemos dizer apenas que você vai ter que encontrar um compilador C/C++ para Android, como, por exemplo, o [NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html), que permite um desempenho absurdo ao ter seu código (compilado em um executável, claro) executado.

Tem também a possibilidade de você compilar e executar seu fonte em um [terminal](https://termux.com/). Essa solução eu já testei, e recomendo, funciona perfeitamente (caso seja um programa sem interface gráfica, os com interface não testei).